# spritekit touches stop working after a few minutes

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

I have built a spritekit flying game similar to flappy bird where the main character uses physics to bring the character down and detect contacts with other things on the screen. On a tap the character has an impulse applied to him to go up. you can slid right causes the character to have an impulse applied that makes him move forward and bounce off of the right side of the screen.

This functionality works great for about 5 minutes and the memory used stays under 140MB which is down from 170MB. After five minutes it stops receiving taps reliably. What I mean is I can tap it sometimes up to 10 times before the character reacts as expected. Other times it may miss just a tap or two. This would be a major flaw in the game for users if the taps are not performing reliably which could cause you to lose the game simply because the character did not react when tapped.

I had previously noticed that the problem happened when the memory got above 150MB but i have reached the conclusion that the memory is not cause as i have been able to make this happen when the memory is only at 130mb. What i do notice is consistent is the time when this happens is after about 5 or 6 minutes. Once i have played about 2 or 3 levels taps become unreliable although they still work 80% of the time. The levels i play do not cause the problem, in a fresh build if i play levels that the problem happened on in a previous builds the problem doesn't happen, only after about 5 minutes of play no matter which level i play first. Even if i play the same level several times in a row it will start to happen after about 5 minutes.

Below is the code that applies the up impulse to the character that isn't always working. As you can see I have an NSLog to let me know if the system received my taps. it does most times, but not every time after about 5 minutes.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Tapping the screen");
    if (disableTouches == NO){
        if(healthHits < 3){
            [hero.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, impulseAmount)];
            heroAttacking = NO;
            [self heroGoingUpSound];
            [self HeroFlapWings];
            UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
            CGPoint location = [aTouch locationInNode:self];
            slideBeginX = location.x;
        }
    }
}
```

My questions is, has anyone else had this problem or a similar problem, and if so how was it solved?

As requested, my code for HeroFlapWings

```
- (void)HeroFlapWings {
    // get reference to the atlas
    SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"firefly2"];
    //get all image filenames
    NSArray *fireflyImages = [atlas textureNames];

    //sort the filenames
    NSArray *sortedNames = [fireflyImages sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    // creat an array to hold the texture images
    NSMutableArray * fireflyTextures = [NSMutableArray array];


    for (NSString *filename in sortedNames){
        SKTexture *texture = [atlas textureNamed:filename];
        [fireflyTextures addObject:texture];
    }

    SKAction *flap = [SKAction animateWithTextures:fireflyTextures timePerFrame:0.1];
    SKAction *keepFlapping = [SKAction repeatAction:flap count:1];

    [hero runAction:keepFlapping];
}
```

Comment: Are you testing this game on the simulator?

Comment: What's happening in `HeroFlapWings`? It sounds like you've got some sort of resource build up somewhere and it's eventually causing unresponsiveness. Maybe you're firing off a new timer somewhere and, after a while, you just have too many running?

Comment: akashg - Yes i am using the simulator to test and the taps are actually clicks on a mouse not my finger on the iPhone screen.

Comment: Mike S - I tested the game again with that call commented out. it still had problems so i also commented out the flap wings of the enemies, no one is flapping wings now but i still have the problem. the code for hero flap wings get images from an atlas.